# How to set the zooming effect in all the subviews of UIScrollView

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiscrollview

I am going through the sample code (https://github.com/vfr/Reader), and tried to add the same zooming effect in all the pages at the same time. for ex: if the user increase the zoom effect in 2nd page it will set the same zoom effect in all the pages. Not getting any idea how to do this...
**Edit:**
    In Short,how to resize all the subviews of UIScrollView according to the zoomin / zoomout.

Comment: Zoomin and zoomout is default feature for scrollView

Answer (score 0):

The reader you are using provides zoom in and zoom out options by default. If that doesn't work just check if you have allowed multiple touches.

Comment: but its working only for the single page.... i mean if u scroll the zoom effect gone

Comment: i want the latest zoom effect in all the pages... it should not resize in the default size.

Comment: In that case you will have to store the zoom level and then when the next page is loaded that is after the scroll you will have to set the zoom level for the new page..

Comment: I tried this but its not working its setting the same zoom effect more than one time... if i use the array and add the pages, in this case the first and last page is not working .... and if on the same page i tried to zoom more than 2 times ... then also its not taking the latest zoom effect

Comment: 1) in ReaderViewController.m pageScaleArray = [NSMutableArray new];
    [pageScaleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",currentPage]];

Comment: 2) in the - (void)showDocumentPage:(NSInteger)page am setting the zooming effect like if (pageScaleArray.count>0) { if ([pageScaleArray indexOfObject:[NSString stringWithFormat: @"%d",page]]==NSNotFound) {[pageScaleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]];NSNumber *key = [NSNumber numberWithInteger:page];ReaderContentView *targetView = [contentViews objectForKey:key];[targetView zoomIncrement];}}else
[pageScaleArray addObject:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d",page]];
currentPage = page;